# is_archive() doesn't work on public query var archive pages?

Tags: query, conditional-tags

> Public query vars are those available and usable via a direct URL
>   query.

E.g.

```
example.net/?category_name=tech&tag=gadgets
```

But doesn't `example.net/?category_name=tech&tag=gadgets` show an **archive**? It definitely uses the `archive.php` template, but for some reason, the `is_archive();` conditional tag doesn't seem to work.

If `is_archive();` isn't the conditional tag to check these archives with, what is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_test_if_archive' );

function my_test_if_archive() {
  global $wp_query;
  $qv = array_keys( $wp_query->query );
  $archives = array('year', 'monthnum', 'day', 'w', 'm', 'author', 'post_type');
  $is_archive = ! empty( array_intersect( $qv, $archives ) );
  $is_tax = ! empty( $wp_query->tax_query->queries );
  if ( $is_archive || $is_tax ) {
    // this is an archive
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But doesn't example.net/?category_name=tech&tag=gadgets show an archive?

Yes, shows, (**is_archive()** returns true) however,

> It definitely uses the archive.php

no, in this case, a `category.php` is used, if not found, then `tag.php` and if any of those files, `archive.php` displays your content.

According to [`template hierarchy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/File:Template_Hierarchy.png), in wordpress *an archive* is everything, that displays a couple of posts, then it is divided into a category archive, a tag archive, a date archive…

**EDIT**

> If is_archive(); isn't the conditional tag to check these archives with, what is?

For this purpose are used is_category(), is_tag()… whole bunch of them [`Conditional Tags`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Comment: `is_archive()` returns true for category, tag, date, et al archives. So I don't understand the point of your answer.

Comment: My bad, maybe I did not get the full idea, what are you asking.  I created an edit, you looking for such an info?

Comment: No. Like I said earlier, in a way, `is_archive()` includes `is_category()`, `is_tag`, etc. -- all archives. But it's not working in my case.

Comment: ok, if you are satisfied with the solution a @G. M. came up with, be it, otherwise I am willing to discuss it to get to the root of the problem. Since, I just don't believe that a function, that is supposed to work, does not. If so, just tell me, in which template you use is_archive?