# Show a 404 error page if Public query variable's value doesn't exist?

Tags: wp-query, query, 404-error, conditional-tags, headers

> Public query vars are those available and usable via a direct URL
>   query.

On my site, I've created some custom URLs with their own query variables like so:

```
example.net/?category_name=uk&tag=highlights
```

(e.g. list posts that belong to both - the 'Tech' category and 'gadgets' tag)

And have rewrite rules (using `add_rewrite_rule`) in place to pretty the URLs, for example, like this:

```
example.net/uk/tag/highlights/
```

(The category base is removed by default from category permalinks.)

Now, the problem with using public query vars is that, they almost never show a 404 error page. For example, take a look these two URLs:

```
example.net/?category_name=uk&tag=jdfjdsjfdlkf
example.net/uk/tag/jdfjdsjfdlkf
```

Even though the tag `jdfjdsjfdlkf` doesn't exist, the visitor is shown a "Nothing found" page (`content-none.php`) instead of throwing a 404 error (404.php) with appropriate headers.

When I think about it, it does make sense. But to suit my specific case, I want a specific set of public query vars (`category_name`, `tag`, and `channel` - a custom taxonomy query_var) to show a 404 error page when the value supplied doesn't exist.

My initial attempts got me here:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
function my_page_template_redirect() {

    global $wp_query, $post;

    $cat = get_query_var( 'category_name' );
    $category = get_term( $cat, 'category' );

    $chnl = get_query_var( 'channel' );
    $channel = get_term( $chnl, 'itsme_channel' );

    $tag = get_query_var( 'tag' );
    $post_tag = get_term( $tag, 'post_tag' );

    if( $category && !is_wp_error($category) && $channel && !is_wp_error($channel) ){
    // If URL is like `example.net/?category_name=uk&channel=tech` and both of the
    // supplied values (i.e. Category and Channel taxonomy terms) exist

        // Do nothing

    } elseif( $category && !is_wp_error($category) && $post_tag && !is_wp_error($post_tag) ) {
    // If URL is like `example.net/?category_name=uk&tag=highlights` and both of the
    // supplied values (i.e. Category and Tag taxonomy terms) exist

        // Do nothing

    } elseif( $category && !is_wp_error($category) && $channel && !is_wp_error($channel) && $post_tag && !is_wp_error($post_tag) ) {
    // If URL is like `example.net/?category_name=uk&channel=tech&tag=highlights` and all the
    // supplied values (i.e. Category, Channel, and Tag taxonomy terms) exist

        // Do nothing

    } else {
    // If one or all of the supplied values don't exist throw a 404 error

        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header(404);
        nocache_headers();

    }
}
```

### Problem

Looks like the conditions in place are wrong, or the term objects (`$category`, `$channel`, `$post_tag` aren't set properly), as I am always shown a 404 error page, i.e. even if the terms exist.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you make it works, you are running 3 different queries (`get_term` fire a query) in addition to the main query for any request, I don't think is the right way to do what you want.

I guess that when you send an invalid tag / category / custom tax you don't find any posts, so why don't

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );

function my_page_template_redirect() {
  global $wp_query;
  if ( ! (int) $wp_query->found_posts > 0 ) {
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header(404);
    nocache_headers();
  }
}
```

---

### Edit

This function return a 404 even if **existing** taxonomies are passed but with no post. someone can find this good, if not this is an alternative not doing so:

```
function my_page_template_redirect() {
  global $wp_query, $wp;
  // this get an array of the query vars in the url
  parse_str( parse_url ( add_query_arg( array() ), PHP_URL_QUERY ), $qv);
  if ( ! empty( $qv ) ) { // if there are some query vars in the url
    $queried = array_keys( $qv ); // get the query vars name
    $valid = $wp->public_query_vars; // this are the valid query vars accepted by WP
    // intersect array to retrieve the queried vars tha are included in the valid vars
    $good = array_intersect($valid, $queried); 
    // if there are no good query vars or if there are at least one not valid var
    if ( empty($good) || count($good) !== count($queried)  ) {
     $wp_query->set_404();
     status_header(404);
     nocache_headers();
    }
  }
}
```

This function will set the 404 only if one or more **invalid** query vars (invalid taxonomy names but not only) are in the query.

Comment: Is there a way I can make the function check if it's an archive of posts displayed by using public query vars in URL? [`is_archive(); doesn't work, I've tried](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/122993/10691). Besides, your function will return a 404 error even if the term exists, but has no posts, doesn't it?

Comment: @its_me have you seen the edit?

Comment: Yes, I have. (Makes sense; but I haven't tested it yet -- have to get back home.) Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I have the special case where I need to throw `404` anyone trying to access `wp-login.php` the code doesn't seem to work ( `is_404` set to `1` but the page still loads) I am hooking with `init`, with `wp` hook; function doesn't run. Any advice?

Comment: `wp` is not fired on `wp-login.php`, but `init` is. However using `init` can be hard to understand if you are in login page at that early hook, use `'login_head'` is probably best choose in your case: it is fired only in `wp-login.php` and is early enough to do a redirect (headers are not already sent). @Sisir

Comment: @gmazzap Nine years later and this is the best answer to come up in a google search.  The default mindset of sending bad queries to site/index.php with a 301 is crazy.  Just finished dealing with a client's hack that poisoned the google crawler with nearly 3mil URLs built around queries. Yours should be the default action. 404 the bad stuff.  It hasn't moved.  Its gone. Kill it. Kill it with fire. Thank you.